# How to make the middle selection point appear sooner?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, zoom

Here I cannot extend my shape vertically because I miss the middle selection point:

[image]

However if I zoom one step further it appears:

[image]

How to make it appear always or sooner in the zoom level?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, there's no option to change that. This is how Illustrator works, and it's the type of feature you should suggest to Adobe themselves.

[According to their blog](https://theblog.adobe.com/requesting-features-or-reporting-bugs-for-illustrator-indesign/), there are four ways that you can provide feedback directly to Adobe:

- Their recommended way is within Illustrator: Navigate to the top menu **Help** and select **Submit Bug/Feature Request**.
- Post Bug/Feature Request to their social media channels.
- Go to the [Adobe Forums](https://forums.adobe.com/) where you can submit feedback.
- Connect with them through [Adobe Support](https://helpx.adobe.com/contact.html).